# Android 4.4 build fails on mac OS X 10.9.4

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to compile AOSP 4.4.4 on mac OS 10.9.4 with java version 1.6. I get the following error when I compile make -j4 for emulator.

```
Export includes file: external/zlib/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libz_intermediates/export_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libz_intermediates/import_includes
Import includes file: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libhardware_intermediates/import_includes
make: *** No rule to make target  `out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libwpa_client_intermediates/export_includes', needed by **`out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libhardware_legacy_intermediates/import_includes'.  Stop.**
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Export includes file: system/core/libnetutils/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libnetutils_intermediates/export_includes
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Can we use java 1.6 for compiling aosp 4.4? Is the problem related to java?

Comment: A web search for "libwpa_client_intermediates" will turn up a number of threads in various locations by people who have investigated the same error message.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for posting back. I looked online but there is no clear solution listed which is not the case in stackoverflow. So I tried to post here so we will have a reference to source problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Xcode 5.1, which comes with Mac OS 10.9, is not compatible with AOSP4.4.4. Try to downgrade it by deleting the Xcode application and installing an older version of it. In my case I installed Xcode 4.6 for Mac 10.9 and it worked.

Comment: How did you figure out Xcode was the problem? I'm having the same but on Ubuntu (without Xcode)...

Comment: I just solved a similar problem.  `libwpa_client` wasn't being built because I incorrectly set `WPA_SUPPLICANT_VERSION := VER_0_8_x` (lower case "x").  That prevented libwpa_client from building due to a version check fail in one makefile (`wpa_supplicant_8/Android.mk`), but one dependency (netd) only cared that `WPA_SUPPLICANT_VERSION` was defined, so it wasn't satisfied.  I'm sure every situation is different, but digging into the makefiles should help.

Comment: One more note: `libwpa_client_intermediates` should be built if the makefiles are setup to define `LOCAL_MODULE = libwpa_client`.  That tip came from this post:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-building/3Bb_Cq5U-MY/JOXj4N6e1d4J

"It seems the code you synced doesn't define a libwpa_client module. 
In a stock AOSP 4.2.2 tree that module should be defined in one of 
external/wpa_supplicant_{6,8}. Note that if $(WPA_SUPPLICANT_VERSION) 
isn't set to a supported value none of those trees will be included 
(see the top-level Android.mk in each of those directories)..."